# Did not see 20 I/O Cycles; giving up occurring in Swift when downloading audio files

Tags: ios, swift, audio

I'm doing some maintenance on some code (unfortunately I didn't write it, so I'm still trying to figure out what was done in this project), and the app downloads several hundred audio files and allows users to play them.

When I attempt to play some of the downloaded audio I'm getting an intermittent bug with the response:

> ERROR:    >aqme> 236: Client(0x7fb329c2ba00) did not see 20 I/O cycles; giving up

Whenever I get this error the audio doesn't play. Does anyone have any insight to what this error means? How to debug it/ideas on what to look for? I haven't found any other stack overflow posts with this bug. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing rate 0 will give error you are getting. 
Are you using player rate? rate is used to set speed. Audio Player normal rate value is 1. 
passing rate 2 will double the speed.
passing 0.5 will half the audio speed. 
Passing rate 0 will give error you are getting.

Comment: I don't believe we are using player rate, but I have noticed that this consistently happens only in the simulator, and most often when I have youtube or spotify playing some sound already

Comment: Thanks for your answer! (Y)

Comment: @Unome any update on this? I'm experiencing the same issue